# CSV import error, with commas in the content, being mistaken for the next column

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to do a page scrape and put the collection of items into a CSV file:

```
Array
        (
            [title] => Ayrshire Brewers Ltd
            [url] => http://www.quaffale.org.uk/php/brewery/982
            [metadata] => (Stevenston, Ayrshire and Arran    1981-1982) 
            [start] => 1981
            [end] => 1982
        )
```

^ so an item would look like this.
--- things go awry when I put the results into the csv -- the comma delimiter mucks up with the metadata comma for example.
-- if I eradicate ALL commas in the data, then it imports smoothly - but this surely can not be the way - how can I escape the comma's in content. I've tried putting quotes around the variable during csv import but it comes back with an error.

```
function makeCSV($filename, $ret){

        $list = array();

        //if array is not empty
        if(key_exists(0, $ret)){

            $keylist = array_keys($ret[0]);
            foreach ($keylist as $key => $value){
                $list[] = $value;
            }
            $implode = implode(",",$list);

            $list = array($implode);

            //put into csv
            foreach($ret as $x => $x_value) {
                $list[] = implode(",",$x_value);
            }
        }



        $file = fopen($filename.".csv","w");
        foreach ($list as $line){
            fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
        }

        fclose($file);       
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the link - Are you able to demonstrate the solution with an accurate correction of the code

Comment: If you have a solution to refactoring a multi-dimensional keyed array - that doesn't appear in the documentation - that will resolve this comma issue - be much appreciated.

Comment: If I could double down vote this, I would.  Why would you ask someone to "correct" your code when you're not willing to read the documentation and do it yourself?

Comment: I think its far easier to copy and paste documentation - instead of spotting the exact line of code in this current base that is causing the issue. I will try and refactor EACH item of the array to see. I do read the documentation - I suppose the reality of the situation is focusing on other issues of a page scrapper, answering other research queries and building reactjs components and other d3.js tools.

Comment: the dimensions of your array are utterly irrelevant. fputcsv only deals with a single dimension/row/record at a time anyways. And what's in your array is irrelevant as well. if you'd bothered actually **READING** the link manual page, you'd see the option you have to give fputcsv to fix your problem. you don't change your array/data. you change how fputcsv DEALS with the data

Comment: Please prove your statement with an actual technical answer solving the code base.

Comment: The problem in the code is `$implode = implode(",",$list);` - you are building the CSV line yourself, which is circumventing the purpose of the CSV function. You can move the `fputcsv()` here to encode the line correctly (PHP will then do the work of wrapping elements with quotes, so that commas are interpreted correctly).

Comment: -- yes several issues here -- you are right halfer the implode was causing a bug -- I think part of this came from trying to add headers to the top of the csv for ease in database importing. But also this code came from another source for a different more simpler page scrap so I didn't pick it up until now. Another bug - was that during the page scrape some coloumns were found, others were not -- but this would cause shifts in the rows. So Marc B, Devlin - more patience would be appreciated - I just put about 15 hours of work in today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that worked - after resolving other bugs in the code, cleaning up html, adding gap columns in the right place if needed.

```
function makeCSV2($filename, $list){
        //header
        $heads = array("title", "brewurl", "metadata", "start", "end", "Address", "lat", "lng", "County (see footnote)", "Phone", "Mobile", "Web", "weburl", "facebook", "twitter", "e-mail", "emailaddress", "History", "Beers Brewed", "Regular Outlets", "Visit Information", "Brewery Shop Information", "postcode");

        array_unshift($list, $heads);//adds the header to the top of the array

        $fp = fopen($filename.".csv","w");

        foreach ($list as $fields){
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp); 
    }
```

Comment: @halfer - the solution found

Comment: __So it imports correctly now -- it didn't help that there were gaps during the scrape - so like some pages didn't have "mobile" - so I had to check for things like this and add empty "coloumns" so to speak.